# Cannot find the installed jdk on my mac

Tags: java, macos

I have installed new version of java 8 on my mac(update 73) but i'm unable to get the installed path.

I already have a java 8 update 65 installed on my mac.

When I do ***/usr/libexec/java_home*** I get my current JDK's path (***/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home***) but not the new one(***update 73***).

I also tried doing ***/usr/libexec/java_home -V*** to see all the versions of java installed on my system but I coudln't find the ***java update 73***

Where it might have got installed?

I'm sure it has got installed as I got the message saying the installation is successful.
[image]

Comment: Questions about installing software are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had installed the JRE instead of JDK and that was the reason I was not able to locate the installed JDK.

Remember to make sure that you are downloading the JDK and not the JRE.